# how to use special utf-8 characters in submodules?

Tags: utf-8, latex

Im trying to write my master-degree thesis with latex and that is my first real project with latex, In my thesis I need japanese and some polish characters.

I divided my thesis by submodules. My main module looks like

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{CJK}

 \includeonly{spis_tresci}

 \begin{document}

 % Definition of title and author
 \title{ My Thesis title. }
 \author{Mazeryt Freager \\
 \\
 \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
  一部の日本人のもの
 \end{CJK*}
 \\ Polish characters are ąćśżźółęń}
 \maketitle

 \clearpage 

 \input{Table_of_Contents}

 \end{document}
```

And the above code works perfect.but the problem is in submodule "Table of Contents"
     %Also I need utf-8 in file header because Table of Contents include "ś" character in PL
     \section{Spis Treści}

```
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{CJK}

 %When I add here something more than ASCI code I got into compilation failure
 %No mather if it is:
 %\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
 %一部の日本人のもの
 %\end{CJK*}
 %\\  Polish characters are ąćśżźółęń}
 abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWXYZ
 %but standard ASCI works
```

I search a lot about this but I didn't find any solution that works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195659/how-to-use-special-utf-8-characters-in-submodules/195690#195690) - I'll post it again here for the sake of completeness.

---

I believe the problem lies in the misconception about the use of the `CJK` environment - as @egreg said, it can't be enabled and disabled. Just enclose the whole document in one `CJK` environment and when using `CJKutf8` (see [here](http://ajt.ktug.org/2008/0201lemberg.pdf) for what difference it makes) utf8 characters using latin script but outside of ASCII will be fine.

Thus your MWE in a fixed version would be:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

% Definition of title and author
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}
\title{My Thesis title.}
\author{Mazeryt Freager\\ \\一部の日本人のもの\\śćóœ}
\maketitle

\clearpage 

\input{Table_of_Contents}
\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

with the `Table_of_Contents.tex' having the following contents:

```
一部の日本人のもの\\
Polish characters are: ąćśżźółęń\\
ASCII: abcdefghijklmnoprstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWXYZ
```

and the output being on the title page:

[image: title page]

and

[image: first page]

on the first page.